# Search only month of a date in database within an if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have posted a form to output data form database.  I am having trouble within my if statement looking to echo all lines that my month form post == the month within my database i.e if my form post was 04 i want it to equal all data that == XXXX/04/XX and echo them all.

At the moment it is not returning anything as the date formats do not match

Thank you in advance.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {//form has been submitted
    $search = new Page();   

    $search->sub_name = $_POST['sub_name'];
    $search->location = $_POST['location'];
    $search->date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
} ?>
<h2>
    <?php echo $search->sub_name; echo " "; echo $search->location;?>
</h2>   

<table class="bordered" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>Course</th> <th>Dates</th> <th>Course Type</th> <th>Location</th><th>Price </th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        $pages = Page::find_all();
        foreach($pages as $page){
            if($search->sub_name == $page->sub_name && $search->location == $page->subject && $search->date_from == $page->date_one('m')) {
                echo "<tbody><tr><td><a href=\"course.php?id=" . urlencode($page->id) . "#type\">" . nl2br($page->course_name) . "</a></td><td>" . nl2br($page->date_from) . "</td><td>" . nl2br($page->sub_name) . "</td><td>" . nl2br($page->subject) . "</td><td>" . nl2br($page->price) . "</td><td><a href=\"hbt_bookings.php?id=" . urlencode($page->id) . "#type\">Book>>></td>" ."</tr></tbody>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do the filtering in the query, not in PHP.

Comment: Stop thinking of the date as a string with a fixed format. that is just convention. Think of it as an object of Year, month Day. Use the date format function to return the month as a digit and compare it to the required month. It is clumsy but it will work. the same technique will work in the database as well. There are many ways to get the month from a date. Go look at the date functions in PHP and SQL. they are very powerful.

Comment: Thank you.  I have worked it out earlier today.  The way Ryan said, creating an object that finds the month and put that object in the if statement.  Works perfectly.